# I want the listview to go up as much as the keyboard appears. (flutter)

Tags: flutter, chat

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Keyboard Adjust Example')),
        body: KeyboardAdjustedView(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class KeyboardAdjustedView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _KeyboardAdjustedViewState createState() => _KeyboardAdjustedViewState();
}

class _KeyboardAdjustedViewState extends State<KeyboardAdjustedView> {
  final TextEditingController _textController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
      },
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: 20,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: Container(
                    color: index % 2 == 0 ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
                    height: 40,
                    width: 500,
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
              left: 8.0,
              right: 8.0,
            ),
            child: TextField(
              controller: _textController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'input text',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want the listview to go up as much as the keyboard appears. (flutter)

However, even when the keyboard appears, scrolling does not work.

I want it to go up and down naturally.

I want to do it like Telegram or other chat messengers. I don't want the keyboard to be covered when it comes up.

look at my source The scroll of the listview does not move even when the keyboard comes up.

T^T